# Email-only subscription form with mailchimp module?

Tags: 6, forms, emails

I have a mailing list in [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) and I recently installed the [mailchimp](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module in my Drupal 6.0 site.

The subscribe form for anonymous users has first name and last name input elements, as well as an (empty and ugly) interest groups div.

Is there a way, using the mailchimp module, to present simply an email+button subscription form block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got a mailchimp enabled Drupal site in front of me, but from memory the simplest way to do it is to set the fields you don't want captured as optional in the Mailchimp interface (NOT the Drupal module) and then just hide the fields using CSS on your subscribe form.

If you don't need to capture anything other than email for your mailing list, you can remove those fields entirely from your list on Mailchimp's site, and (again from memory) they won't show up in your Drupal form.

Comment: Thanks. Both workarounds make sense, if I don't find a more subtle solution I'll go for one of them.

Comment: You can also use hook_form_alter to either set those form elements to hidden, remove them completely, or set a custom theme function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide elements (such as the groups area) with CSS, using

`display: none;`

Mailchimp actually recommends doing this in the case where you want to have people automatically subscribed to a specific group (without giving them the choice).

As long a given field isn't required, you could hide it this way.